How to export a Unity prefab asset to tabletop simulator
I've recently downloaded Tabletop Simulator on steam and I will be running a D&D campaign for a group of friends. I would like to make my own tiles for the game. The simulator accepts .unity3d files but not .unitypackage files. Ive built a basic grass tile in Unity and would like to move it and future tiles over. Is this possible and if so how? Additionally I would be willing to take recommendations on other software if it is not possible.

Usually a .unity3d file is an asset bundle. https://kb.tabletopsimulator.com/custom-content/custom-assetbundle/
